# I need to convert the interest rate to a decimal value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following which should return a value of the interest where it should be divided by 100. How do I implement this?

```
import math

p = int(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount: \n"))
r = float(raw_input("Please input interest rate: \n")) /100
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the investment: \n"))
interest = raw_input("Do you want a simple or compound interest ? \n")

A = p*(1+r*t) 
B = p*(1+r)^t 

if interest == "simple":
print (float(A))
else:
print(float(B))
```

Comment: What, you mean `A / 100`?

Comment: Note that you should use `**` Python's exponation operator and not `^` which is bitwise XOR: `B = p*(1+r)**t`.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: Why not just `r = float(raw_input("...")) / 100`?

Comment: Side-note: `float` is a terrible type to use for monetary calculations. I _strongly_ recommend [using `decimal.Decimal` for monetary calculations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Ive updated it and it didnt work. with the 

r = float(raw_input("...")) / 100

Comment: @Duvall912: Did you also replace the use of `^` with `**` to get actual exponentiation? And can you specify what "didn't work" means? "didn't work" is possibly the least helpful statement you can make when it comes to solving a problem. __Edit__: Your update makes it clear you didn't fix the issue with `^`; `^` is bitwise-xor, not the power operator. Also, no need to convert to `float` again in the `print`s; the value is already `float`.

Comment: improper indentation. pls fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (Hint you don't need to `import math` for something like this):

```
from decimal import *

p = Decimal(raw_input("Please enter deposit amount:"))
r = Decimal(raw_input("Please input interest rate as a percentage:")) /100
t = int(raw_input("Please insert number of years of the investment:"))
n = 1 # You should really be asking how many times is the interest compounded per year? If the user chooses compound...

A = p*(1 + r)**t
B = p*(1 + r)**(n*t)

while(True):
  interest = raw_input("Do you want simple or compound interest?")
  if(interest.lower() == "simple"):
    print(A)
    break
  elif(interest.lower() == "compound"):
    print(B)
    break
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/EidP/0)